# Autodesk Construction Cloud - how to upload linked Revit models to generate a composite URN for Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

With BIM360Docs, there was a way to upload a master Revit model with linked models together to produce a single composite model that generates a single urn for Forge Viewer. How do we do that in Construction Cloud? I cannot figure out how to upload a model set ACC Docs.

Thanks

Bandu

Comment: from the API or on the product? sorry the question is not clear.

Comment: I did more experiments, and let me rephrase the issue I have. When we make a federated model using ACC collaborate, I get a single URN but Levels and Rooms are gone (in Forge Viewer). How do we carry forward Levels and Rooms? Thanks.